# I18n::InvalidLocaleData rails error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am little confused in using rails yaml file.

My app throwing following error

```
I18n::InvalidLocaleData
```

My yaml file is

```
en:
  auth:
    register:
        success: "Successfully registered"
        error: "Please correct the errors"
```

My controller is

```
class AuthController < ApplicationController

def register
    blahblah
    flash[:error] = t '.auth.register.error'
end
```

Can anyone help how to use yaml. I checked with [yamlint](http://yamllint.com/) it shows `valid YAML`

Comment: Try: `flash[:error] = t 'auth.register.error'` without the leading `dot`

Comment: @vinodadhikary tried without `dot` it doesn't help

Comment: Is that all  your YAML file contains?  If so it's difficult to debug, can you post your log when this occurs, it might be worth looking at what call generates this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't your indentation wrong between the `register:` and the `success: "Successfully registered"` lines? It seems that you have 2 more spaces there, also keep in mind that you have to use spaces and avoid tabs, make sure you're using spaces.

Comment: Yea i have 2 more spaces i corrected but facing with this error after correcting it `translation missing: en.auth.create.auth.register.error`

Comment: Your view is probably named "create" or something like this, this error happen because of the leading `dot`, this `dot` tries to tell to rails to use the view's path in the YAML, try to remove the leading `dot` now. Post the result if it doesn't solve =)